# Shortcode element pushing main content down 2px

Tags: wordpress, google-translate

I just added the wordpress plugin "google translate" shortcode to my header on my wordpress site.

When it loads, it's pushing the page content down about 2px and ruins the layout a bit. How can I keep it from doing this?

http://www.the2hourchallenge.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
margin-top: -2px;
```

for your

`google_language_translator div`

Comment: Thank you Vaibs! That works in my inspector. But how can I find the file path to this file so I can edit it? The css inspector says: www.the2hourchallenge.com #4

Answer (score 0):

Just comment down this css
    `.goog-te-gadget {margin-top:2px !important}`

Comment: Hi Desh, where is the file that I need to edit? I cant find this in the plugin style.css

Comment: can you please tell the name of plugin you are using?

Comment: Yes: Google Language Translator

Comment: File name: wp-content/plugins/google-language-translator/google-language-translator.php. Line No. 1638. $str.='.goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {margin: 2px 0px !important;}';

Comment: Please go through these line numbers as well if needed 1662, 1695 and 
1722.